# ionic build errors after installing ionic2-calendar

Tags: ionic3, node-modules, ionic2-calendar

everything worked fine until I was installing ionic-calendar.

Here are some of the errors (too much to show all):

[image]

The errors dont really make sense.

Did anybody have the same problem and solved it?
Im trying to solve it the whole day and have no more idea what to do.

Im thankful for any help :)

System datas:

[image]

Comment: Which version of ionic2-calendar did you install ?

Comment: Try this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar`

Comment: @saperlipopette The latest version. I ran >npm i ionic2-calendar